# Trying to install twodict, confused about command/directory?

Tags: directory, installation

I am completely new to all of this, but I was trying to install https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/youtube-dl-gui, which requires twodict.

Now, the manual simply says:

> #### Install From Source
>
> 1. Download & extract source from [here](https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/twodict/archive/1.2.zip)
> 2. Change directory into **twodict-1.2/**
> 3. Run `sudo python setup.py install`

Sorry for the idiotic question, but what is meant by "change directory into twodict-1.2/"?

I downloaded the source file, and when I extract it, where do I put it? If What is meant by the step 2? Which command would I have to run exactly? I don't get it.

Running MacOS.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to open Terminal and do a `cd <dirname>` until you reach that directory

Comment: That worked and makes sense now! Thank you!